# Can I Prevent a Browser Add-in from working or Obfuscate Content

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iis, obfuscation

We have an ASP.Net web application that is available to users within a highly regulated industry. Part of the regulations are to do with protection of data.

Unfortunately, a third party company has created an IE add-in that performs HTML injection on our site (inserting buttons in certain pages), and also screen-scrapes our pages for data. It has an additional side-effect of breaking some of our features too.

Beyond the legal issue here (that's being followed up elsewhere), we need to be able to stop them scraping this data/inserting their content onto our site. Unfortunately, the steps we've taken thus far are only temporary - changing ids, adding non-printable characters, etc. After a week or so, they adapt to our change and continue.

I did consider that the IIS pipeline may be capable of encrypting the content in some manner that can change form regularly (e.g. daily/weekly), but I'm not sure if it is able to do this. IIS seems like the best place for something like this though - since we can apply it easily to all outgoing content.

Is there any way we can either completely disable their add-in, or obfuscate our content in some manner that makes it near-impossible for them to adapt. Preferably in some manner thats randomised?

Comment: You could try detecting the add-in and totally disabling the whole page if it is present. You probably don't want users using that add-in anyway, even if it did nothing.

Comment: I've suggested that, but management want to shut down the add-in without preventing the users accessing the page(s) in question. It would certainly be my preferred solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

You have no control over anything that happens on the client.

Comment: What about before it leaves our servers? Anything that would randomise/obfuscate the html ids, etc?

Comment: That's what you're doing already, they're still catching up. If you do it faster, they'll just find some other way to get the data out of the DOM that doesn't depend on ids.

Comment: @ObsidianPhoenix Also, as you're also probably noticing, you're (going to/thinking of/planning to) doing a lot on your end that ultimately affects _all_ your users (performance degradation for _everyone_). A user who has such browser plugin opted for it. It would't be any different from a "legitimate" plugin - e.g. McAfee (adds some check to what it says is an "ok" link, etc.)...

Comment: Yeah, thats pretty much exactly what we're seeing. If we change it, they just update and continue. Unfortunately (for reasons above my paygrade), management have decreed that is has to be blocked. Looks like we just need to work on updating ours faster than theirs until they give up. Welcome to a game of resource chicken!